# Manipulating product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, logarithms

In a published paper I saw the following

$$\log \left(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{T}\mathbf {Hpp^HH^H}\right)= \log(1+\mathbf {p^HH^HTHp})$$

where uppercase means a matrix while lower case means vector and $()^H$ means cojugate transpose of matrix and this was justified by the following

$$|\mathbf{I+XY}| = |\mathbf{I+YX}|$$

where $\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{T}\mathbf {Hp}$ while $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{p^HH^H}$

I have a slightly different problem

$$\log \left(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{T}\mathbf {w^HHH^Hw}\right)=???$$
and I am trying replace the argument by scalar as the authors of paper did.

Looking forward for help

Comment: In your problem dimension of matrices are not fit.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. Can you please provide more details

Comment: Well, you are multiplying $T$ by a scalar, so maybe that is what he is referring to, but multiplying matrices by scalars is a valid operation, so I also don't see that as a problem.

Comment: you meant $\log\det(...) = \log|...|$ instead of $\log(...)$, right?

Comment: that is correct ...

Comment: please edit your post accordingly...